# User-defined compile-time type constraints in C#

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I'm currently experimenting with generics in C#, and came up with the following challenge to myself:

Given a generic function `f<T>`, validate during compile time that T is a type from a given set [T1, T2, ..., Tn]. For instance, if in `f<T>` we have

```
CompileTimeAssert<T>.isContainedIn<TypeList<string, int, bool>>();
```

then `f<int>` should compile, and `f<double>` should not compile.

I'm not quite there yet. This is what I have so far:

```
interface ContainsType<T> {}

class TypeList<T1>: ContainsType<T1> {} 
class TypeList<T1, T2>: TypeList<T2>, ContainsType<T1>  {}
class TypeList<T1, T2, T3>: TypeList<T2, T3>, ContainsType<T1> {}
class TypeList<T1, T2, T3, T4>: TypeList<T2, T3, T4>, ContainsType<T1> {}
// add longer type lists to taste

class CompileTimeAssert<T>
{
    public static void isContainedIn<TypeList>()
        where TypeList: ContainsType<T> {}
    public static void isContainedIn<TypeList>(TypeList tl)
        where TypeList: ContainsType<T> {}
}
```

Given the code above, the following compiles (as expected):

```
 // uses first overload
CompileTimeAssert<int>.isContainedIn<TypeList<string, int, bool>>();

var myTypeList = new TypeList<string, bool>();
CompileTimeAssert<string>.isContainedIn(myTypeList); // uses second overload
```

And the following does not compile, also as expected:

```
CompileTimeAssert<short>.isContainedIn<TypeList<string, int, bool>>();

var myTypeList = new TypeList<string, bool>();
CompileTimeAssert<double>.isContainedIn(myTypeList);
```

That's all very cute, but also useless. It would become much more useful if one could do the following:

```
void f<T>()
{
    CompileTimeAssert<T>.isContainedIn<TypeList<string, int, bool>>();
}
```

and then have `f<int>` compile, and `f<double>` result in a compilation error.

Alas, `f<T>` as given above fails to compile (regardless of any calls with concrete types).
I'm getting the following error (using MonoDevelop on Mac OS X):

> Error CS0311: The type `TypeList<string,int,bool>' cannot be used as type parameter
>   'TypeList' in the generic type or method 'CompileTimeAssert<T>.isContainedIn<TypeList>()'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from`TypeList' to
>   'ContainsType'

I kind of understand why this doesn't work, but so far, I haven't been able to come up with a working alternative. Does anyone have any ideas on whether what I want is possible at all in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: You would probably have better luck implementing this functionality using aspect oriented programming. Take a look at PostSharp to see if it can help you: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/

Comment: You really should prefix your interfaces with `I`

Comment: M.Babcock: thanks, PostSharp looks cool and promising, and I'll put it on my "check this out" list. It may take a while before I get to it, as I just started learning C#.

Comment: Nico: ContainsType is not meant to be used as an interface; I'm just abusing the type system here. It needs to be an interface since C# doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of your challenge is useless, because generics of .NET are as much a run-time construct as a compile-time construct. Even if your program compiles without an error, one could still expand your generic through reflection, passing a "non-approved" type.

I understand where you are coming from (I loved that book by Andrei Alexandrescu very much, too) but an important thing to understand about C# generics is that **generics are not C++ templates**. Apart from the small syntactic similarities, they are not even that close: "ain't the same ballpark, ain't the same league, ain't even the same sport". The major driving force behind the need to do compile-time validation of the sort "ints are OK, doubles are not OK) was that you *could* access operations implicitly: `a+b` would succeed if the types of `a` and `b` supplied at template expansion allowed the `+` operation. It is not the same in C#: if you want an operation to be done on a value passed to a generic, you must either stipulate the existence of that operation explicitly through a type constraint, or provide an explicit way to perform that operation (a delegate, an interface, etc.) Either way, telling the compiler that your template works for ints nut not for doubles does not buy you absolutely anything.

Comment: I understand that generics and templates are very different; I just started learning C#, and experiments like these help me to understand how things work. The "need" for constraints checking comes from playing with alternatives for a "Settings" class (managing mappings from string to T for a limited set of types T). Design criteria were a.o. (1) client code should not need to cast (2) no duplication of code (3) calls to get settings of a not-supported type should ideally not compile. One option would be st like `mySettings.get<T>("settingName")`, and here type validation would come in handy.

Comment: @RenévanOostrum As fat as implementing string conversion to target type goes, .NET offers a very good class called [StringConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k3hsy2h.aspx).It offers convert methods that return objects; your `get<T>` method could then type-cast them to `T`.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of conversion, but of lookup, i.e., the Settings class has several Dictionary<string, T> members for a limited set of T's. The get<T> function would do validation before returning the value. This way, I wouldn't have to write a get_int(string), get_bool(string), and so on. Checking for unsupported types T in get<T> is easy enough to do during runtime, but I'd prefer a get<T> on an unsupported T simply not to compile. That's where the experimentation came in.

Comment: Prior to the existence of extension methods, there wouldn't much advantage to constraints that didn't add to a type's abilities.  Extension methods and Intellisense change that, though.  For example, a `HasAnyFlag<T>(this T enum1, T enum2) where T:struct` method can vastly (by an order-of-magnitude) outperform `Enum.HasFlag` but it's annoying having `HasAnyFlag` pop up as an option with every value type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how what you are trying to do could be possible with generics.

What would be the purpose of such a generic class (doesn't compile, it's here for the example):

```
public class GenericClass<T>
    where T : A
    where T : B
    where T : C
{
    public T MyMember { get; set; }

    public GenericClass(T myMember)
    {
        this.MyMember = myMember;
    }
}
```

- If it means "T must be A and B and C", then it's not possible as multi-inheritance doesn't exist in C#.
- If it means "T must be A or B or C", then:

  - If A, B and C have nothing in common, then the GenericClass has no purpose: what logic would you implement with `MyMember` as there isn't anything in common for the 3 classes ?
  - If A, B anc C have something in common, then all classes implement a particular interface or inherit from the same base class, and you'll use this interface or base class for the `where` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, because C# generic functions are required to pass type checking based only on the constraints.  Actual type parameters aren't considered, because generics are not specialized.

The only thing you've promised is that (implicitly) `T : object`.

So the compiler type-checks

```
CompileTimeAssert<object>.isContainedIn<TypeList<string, int, bool>>();
```

and this (correctly) fails to compile.

On the other hand you could write:

```
void f<T>() where T : Form
{
    CompileTimeAssert<T>.isContainedIn<TypeList<string, Control>>();
}
```

and it would compile, since every `Form` is-a `Control`.